# Как оценить сложность алгоритма в зависимости от IF?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Допустим есть такой код:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)   
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)   
        if(...)
        {} else {}
```

Тут сложность будет `i * j` или `if` добавит сложность и будет что-то в духе `i*j * 2` к примеру?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/104219/

Comment: вы имеете в виду вычислительную сложность? или цикломатическую?

Comment: Вычислительная сложность имеет смысл только по отношению к какому-то параметру. Если все параметры фиксированы, то у вас чистый `O(1)`.

Comment: Да-да, именно        
У парнишки, на сколько я понял, параметрами являются размеры 3-х массивов. (значение 10 для определенности взял)

Comment: @Stas0n: а где в коде третий массив? Пока вижу `O(N1 * N2)`.

Comment: Вообще у парнишки задача, связанная с размерами 3-х массивов. В примере привел лишь два

Answer (score 1):

смотри, итоговая сложность будет зависеть от того, что происходит внутри `if`
Сложность `i * j` набирается только из двух циклов.
Общая сложность будет произведением `i * j * (сложность того, что в if)`

Comment: Процесс намечается такой. Будет несколько массивов. Будет бинарное дерево, при каждом добавлении я в элементе дерева буду повышать счетчик на 1 и если там будет цифра 3, то закидываю это в еще один массив. Нужно отследить элементы, которые встречаются во всех трех массивах, не привышая сложности алгоритма, который будет равен сумме их размеров.

Comment: >> Сложность i * j набирается только из двух циклов. 

а условие может быть `if (i == j)`, что сразу понижает сложность.

Для оценки сложности нужен полный алгоритм и детальное исследование.

Comment: @KoVadim, сложность меньше, чем i*j быть не может

Comment: ок, какая сложность у алгоритма

   for (int i = 0; i<max_i; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < max_j; j++)
       if (i==j) do_some_action();

если `do_some_action` средней сложности функция? O(n^2) ( это Ваш `i*j`) или O(n).

Comment: О (max_i * max_j * (сложность do_some_action()))